# pymc3 on windows10/cygwin64/python3.6 core dumps at import statement

Tags: python, cygwin, windows-10, python-3.6, pymc3

Any thoughts on what to try when installation of pymc3, using pip, works flawlessly, but as soon as the statement import pymc3 is executed, Python3.6 coredumps ?

$ python3.6
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 21 2017, 21:49:16)
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pymc3
> > >       Segmentation fault (minnesutskrift skapad)

TIA,
Tommy

Comment: Are you in windows 10 pro? Can you put it in a docker? Did you manage to install Theano successfully? Should at least import without it, but I'm trying to think about what else might be wrong.

Comment: Windows 10 Home. Theano installed, and no problems doing 'import theano'.  Have no experience of Docker, might have to take a look at it.

Comment: You need pro or edu for docker, unfortunately. It's a windows limitation driving it, so there isn't an easy way around it. 

I remember having trouble installing theano on Windows, especially for later versions of python-3 since I didn't think they were supported. You're sure Theano is properly installed? I wonder if that could be contributing.

Comment: More support for it being a theano issue: 
https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/2266

Comment: latest cygwin python is 3.6.4. Have you tried to update the cygwin packages ?

Comment: I'll start an upgrade of cygwin and see what happens. Stay tuned. Wrt Theano: I dont use it explicitly, but at least it imports ok, which pymc3 doesnt.

Comment: Upgraded Cygwin to latest, including Python 3.6.4. Got a bit further, but not much: now the import statement fails with a HDFS Library version mismatch error. Not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: After being unable to get pymc3 working, I decided to try pystan instead, and it works, i.e. I'm able to solve my computation using pystan instead.

Comment: Still trying to get pymc3 working. Have now reinstalled "everything", including building hdf5 from sources, but to no avail: now pymc3 imports ok, but crashes when trying a simple example, with:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/tensor/type.py", line 269, in dtype_specs
    }[self.dtype]
KeyError: 'object'

Interestingly, exactly the same error occurs if I run the same code in Anaconda.